# Azure Cli giving me permission error when typing "az login"

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have just installed Azure Cli and when I am trying to login to my Azure account using az login it gives me an error -

```
The error - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.28.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/core/_session.py", line 48, in load
    with codecs_open(self.filename, 'r', encoding=self._encoding) as f:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 905, in open
    file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/mawada14/.azure/azureProfile.json'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.28.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/__main__.py", line 38, in <module>
    az_cli = get_default_cli()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.28.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 912, in get_default_cli
    return AzCli(cli_name='az',
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.28.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 80, in __init__
    ACCOUNT.load(os.path.join(azure_folder, 'azureProfile.json'))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.28.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/core/_session.py", line 61, in load
    self.save()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.28.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/core/_session.py", line 65, in save
    with codecs_open(self.filename, 'w', encoding=self._encoding) as f:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 905, in open
    file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/mawada14/.azure/azureProfile.json'
```

Comment: Are you trying this as a `sudo` user?

Answer (score 0):

I just came accross the same issue, seems like during install on linux the `.azure` directory doesn't get assigned the right permissions for the client to work somehow.

I started manually setting the permissions with chmod like this:

```
sudo chmod 777 $HOME/.azure/az.sess
sudo chmod 444 $HOME/.azure/config
sudo chmod 777 $HOME/.azure/versionCheck.json
sudo chmod 777 $HOME/.azure/commandIndex.json
# At this point I had enough and just added all permissions to the whole folder
sudo chmod 777 $HOME/.azure/*
```

By doing this I managed to do a successful login

Answer (score -1):

I followed this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli) and able to login my azure portal using CLI cmd  `az login`.

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:

. [Permission denied' error after running 'az login | GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/613).

.[Sign in with Azure CLI | MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli)

Answer (score -1):

Delete the **C:/users/your-user-name/.azure directory** and reinstall Azure cli from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli It works.